# Как убрать скобки в ComboBox

Tags: java, postgresql, javafx

Итак суть в том что мне нужно выбранный элемент из ComboBox вывести в TextField но так как я ввожу данные в ComboBox через массив (данные из моей БД) то этот элемент вставляется со скобками вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам ComboBox выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот вопрос что мне нужно сделать что бы эти скобки убрать
Вот так я заполняю ComboBox:

```
public ObservableList<String> BoxEnter1() {
    Connection box;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    box = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection();
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String PostSQL = "SELECT name_of_organization FROM " + Constant.TABLE_OF_ORGANIZATION;
    ObservableList<String> row = null;
    try {
        // Execute query and store result in a resultset
        rs = box.createStatement().executeQuery(PostSQL);
        while (rs.next()) {
            row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error" + ex);
    }
    Box1.setItems(data);
    return row;
}
```

А вот так я вывожу из ComboBox в TextField:

```
Box1.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        organization1.setText(String.valueOf(Box1.getValue()));
    });
```

Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что вы скопировали получение данных из примера для таблицы. В таблице каждая строка - список элементов. При вызове метода `toString()` (явном или внутри какого-нибудь метода) у списка, он превращается в строку, в которой в **квадратных скобках** через запятую перечислены элементы списка (отсюда появились квадратные скобки).

Вам нужно получить из результата запроса просто "плоский" список строк, тогда никаких квадратных скобок не будет:

```
ObservableList<String> data;

// ...

data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
String PostSQL = "SELECT name_of_organization FROM " + Constant.TABLE_OF_ORGANIZATION;

try {
    // Execute query and store result in a resultset
    rs = box.createStatement().executeQuery(PostSQL);
    while (rs.next()) {
        // Внутренний цикл не нужен, просто берем первое значение (name_of_organization) из каждой строки результата запроса
        data.add(rs.getString(0));
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println("Error" + ex);
}

Box1.setItems(data);
return data;
```

Соответственно, нужно поменять тип у `ComboBox` на `ComboBox<String>` (предполагаю, что у вас там сейчас тип `ComboBox<ObservableList<String>>`).

Comment: Большое спасибо все сработало